# Can I assign a new spark service to my notebook?

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, jupyter-notebook

Today I decided to create a new spark service under bluemix and deleted the old one. I have 4-5 notebooks under a project, and they all used the old spark service and now the notebook status shows as unknown.

can someone guide me here how I can assign these notebooks with the new spark service?

Comment: Remove 'Thanks, AZ' as this is considered noise.

Comment: Also, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can update the Spark service. I think your best bet is to download the notebook and create a new one from the downloaded file. You can download the file by opening the notebook and selecting File > Download as > Notebook (.ipynb). When you create the new notebook choose "From File", select the ipynb file, and select your new Spark instance.